# Trying to determine smallest amount and position in a Java array

Tags: java

I am new to the site, and new to programming in general, so please be gentle.  I'm doing an assignment and I've built everything it needs, but I'm having problems with one particular part.

So the code below is just the for loop part of the overall program that I'm having trouble with.  I created an array to store the user's quarterly input.  When I go to determine which quarter had the largest rainfall, the code works no problem.

Where I'm having problems however is when I try to determine the quarter with the least amount.  I basically set them both up the same way, but it doesn't work.  I'm sure I must have a logic problem somewhere in there, but I've racked my brain trying to figure it out.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sure its something small and stupid that I'm doing.

```
double largest=0;
for (int k = 0; k < quarterlyArray.length; k++) { // Determines the largest quarterly rainfall.
  if ( quarterlyArray[k] >= largest ) {
    largest = quarterlyArray[k];
  }
}

for (int k = 0; k < quarterlyArray.length; k++) { // Determines in which quarter had largest rainfall.
  if (quarterlyArray[k] == largest) {
    System.out.println("Quarter " + (k+1) + " saw the most rain this year with " + largest + " inches.");
  }
}

double smallest = 0;  
for (int p = (quarterlyArray.length-1); p == 0; p--) { // This is not working right now. 
  if (quarterlyArray[p] < quarterlyArray [quarterlyArray.length-1] ||  quarterlyArray[p] < smallest) {
    quarterlyArray[p] = smallest;
  }
}

for (int l = quarterlyArray.length; l == 0; l--) { // Nor this.
  if (quarterlyArray[l] == smallest) {
    System.out.println("Quarter " + (l+1) + " saw the least rain this year with " + smallest + " inches.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work?" Is it looping too many times? Not at all?

Comment: If you change `l == 0` to `l >= 0` the for loops will be executed, and should throw an indexOutOfBoundsException, your `quarterlyArray.length` needs to be `quarterlyArray.length - 1`

Comment: Look how the first loop starts with a value that is known to be smaller than every element, and modifies the largest variable. The other one should start with a value that is known to be larger than every element, and should modify the smallest variable, not the elements of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things that I notice, that are contributing to your problem:

```
for (int p = (quarterlyArray.length-1); p == 0; p--) {
```

The `p == 0` is the [*termination expression*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). Your loop will only iterate while this condition is `true`. Your loop will not execute because the condition is `false` on the first iteration.

```
for (int l = quarterlyArray.length; l == 0; l--) {
```

Same problem in this loop, too. Look at your condition in your first for loop - `k < quarterlyArray.length`. When this is `false`, your loop will terminate.

```
quarterlyArray[p] = smallest
```

You are modifying the array rather than your local variable `smallest`.

You also need to be careful about bounds of the arrays. Your loop sets `l` to the array length - `int l = quarterlyArray.length`. If you then try to index into this array using `quarterlyArray[l]` you would get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because Java arrays (and most programming languages I would say) are [0-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering).

Another thing to point out is how you are calculating both the `min` and `max`. Say, for example, that your `quarterlyArray` contains all negative values. What would `largest` be? Well, none of the items in the array are greater than `0`, so `largest` would be 0. That would be incorrect because that value is not in the array.

In your first case, it looks like you are starting with an element that you know will *always be lower than the elements in the array*. This works out fine if you know all the elements will be greater than that. Your `double largest = 0` will be changed to the maximum value of the array based on the constraints of the problem you are solving.

A better way to approach this is to start with a *known element from the array*. If you simply change your `largest` to be the first/last element from the array, and then go through the rest, you will always come out with the desired result.

```
double largest = quarterlyArray[0];
for (int k = 1; k < quarterlyArray.length; k++) { // Determines the largest quarterly rainfall.
  if ( quarterlyArray[k] >= largest ) {
    largest = quarterlyArray[k];
  }
}
```

Notice how all I changed was the initialization of `largest`, and `int k = 1`. You can do the same thing for `smallest`. In this case, I start from the end of the array.

```
double smallest = quarterlyArray[quarterlyArray.length - 1];  
for (int p = quarterlyArray.length - 2; p >= 0; p--) {right now. 
  if (quarterlyArray[p] < smallest) {
    smallest = quarterlyArray[p];
  }
}
```

Another note for after you get through this, is how could do both in 1 `for` loop?

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!  It always helps to have objective eyes looking at your bone-head mistakes!

Answer (score 1):

Start the last  loop form `quarterlyArray.length-1`.Change to

```
for (int l = quarterlyArray.length-1; l >= 0; l--)
```

The last element of the array would be at `quarterlyArray.length-1` not at `quarterlyArray.length`

And `l == 0`(**termination expression**) should be `l >= 0` because **when the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.**

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it's from the `l == 0` part of the for loop

Answer (score 1):

Your loop for the smallest is all wrong - you are setting the array values, not finding the smallest.
Do it all in one loop:

```
double largest=Double.MIN_VALUE;
double smallest = Double.MAX_VALUE;
for (int k = 0; k < quarterlyArray.length; k++) {
  if ( quarterlyArray[k] > largest ) {
     largest = quarterlyArray[k];
  }
  if ( quarterlyArray[k] < smallest ) {
     smallest = quarterlyArray[k];
  }
}
```

You can also refine this in the manner shown by @mkobit to make it a bit faster:

```
double largest=quarterlyArray[0];
double smallest = largets;
for (int k = 1; k < quarterlyArray.length; k++) {
  if ( quarterlyArray[k] > largest ) {
     largest = quarterlyArray[k];
  } else if ( quarterlyArray[k] < smallest ) {
     smallest = quarterlyArray[k];
  }
}
```

Of course, you should first check to ensure that `quarterlyArray` has a length greater than zero.